# Problemas no código Api Youtube - Importação da classe

Tags: java, api, youtube-api

Boa noite!

Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa utilizando a API do youtube, porem estou tendo dificuldades referente a uma classe : "com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;". Não estou encontrando na internet. Peço ajuda em encontrar essa classe para importação ou uma forma de contorna o problema.

Comment: Já baixou a lib daqui? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download

Comment: Boa tarde, Já baixei sim. Porem é o único que não encontra.

Comment: Estou com dificuldades nesse trecho do código:                          
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT,Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-geolocationsearch-sample").build();

Answer (score -1):

Pergunta (muito) antiga, mas para fins de registros, precisa é desse import também:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: downvote sem comentário não ajuda em absolutamente nada, deveria haver downvote de downvote